# How to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\arctan(\tan^2 x)\over \sin^2 x\sqrt{\tan x}}\cdot(3\pm\tan x)\mathrm dx=2\pi\sqrt{2\pm \sqrt{2}}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**A bit of messy integral but seem to yield a simple closed form**

Given that:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\arctan(\tan^2 x)\over \sin^2 x\sqrt{\tan x}}\cdot(3\pm\tan x)\mathrm dx=2\pi\sqrt{2\pm \sqrt{2}}\tag1$$

Simplifying this part doesn't yield a simple from.

$${3+\tan x\over \sin^2 x\sqrt{\tan x}}$$

Else we can split the integral $(1)\implies$

$$3\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\arctan(\tan^2 x)\over \sin^2 x\sqrt{\tan x}}\mathrm dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sqrt{\tan x}\arctan(\tan^2 x)\over \sin^2 x}\mathrm dx=I+J\tag2$$

$$2\sin^2x=1-{1-\tan^2 x\over 1+\tan^2 x}$$

$$\sin^2x={\tan^2x\over 1+\tan^2x}$$

$$I=3\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{1+\tan^2x\over \tan^2x}\cdot{\arctan(\tan^2 x)\over \sqrt{\tan x}}\mathrm dx$$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{1+\tan^2x\over \tan^2x}\cdot{\sqrt{\tan x}\arctan(\tan^2 x)}\mathrm dx$$

$$u=\tan^2x\implies du=2\tan x\sec^2xdx=2u^{1/2}+2u^{3/2}$$

$I+J\implies$

$${3\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1+u\over u^{7/4}+u^{11/4}}\arctan(u)\mathrm du+{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1+u\over u^{5/4}+u^{9/4}}\arctan(u)\tag3$$

simplify to

$${3\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1\over u^{7/4}}\arctan(u)\mathrm du+{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1\over u^{5/4}}\arctan(u)\tag4$$

$${1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}(3+u^{1/2}){\arctan(u)\over u^{7/4}}\mathrm du\tag5$$

$$u=v^4\implies du=4v^3dv$$

$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}(3+v^2){\arctan(v^4)\over v^4}\cdot{\mathrm dv}\tag6$$

**Q: How can we prove $(1)?$**

Comment: What is the question, anyway?

Comment: Is it possible you use the sign =? (1)=(6)?

Comment: the function $f(x)=\dfrac{3+x^2}{x^4}$ has an anti-derivative. Never heard of integration by parts?

Comment: @FDP i always wonder what this user(S) learns from our answers. He always gets stuck at the same points and seems not to remember (or look up) the techniques used to answer his other questions

Comment: This is the third question of yours that can be solved in the same way: a substitution and Feynman's trick. It might be a good moment to start learning from experience.

Comment: It reminds me someone who was changing frequently his nickname with his account suspended.  Lot of questions, very few answers !

Comment: Search for users abdi, mr-bean, probably same person.

Comment: Watch this FDP and Tired it is Mr bean in class https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ocd1D8fwdjU

Comment: Hi @tired, guy like me are not yet have the abilities to understand even a 5% of the given answers so far I have been here on this site. Honestly with you boredom make me come here and post questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\arctan\pars{\tan^{2}\pars{x}} \over
> \sin^{2}\pars{x}\root{\tan\pars{x}}}\,\bracks{3 \pm \tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
> 2\pi\root{2 \pm \root{2}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\arctan\pars{\tan^{2}\pars{x}} \over
\sin^{2}\pars{x}\root{\tan\pars{x}}}\,\bracks{3 \pm \tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] & =
\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}
{\tan^{2}\pars{x} + 1 \over \tan^{2}\pars{x}}
{\arctan\pars{\tan^{2}\pars{x}} \over
\bracks{\tan^{2}\pars{x}}^{1/4}}\,\bracks{3 \pm \bracks{\tan^{2}\pars{x}}^{1/2}}
\,\times
\\[3mm] & \phantom{=\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}}
{\dd\bracks{\tan^{2}\pars{x}} \over 2\bracks{\tan^{2}\pars{x}}^{1/2}\bracks{\tan^{2}\pars{x} + 1}}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\tan^{2}\pars{x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\arctan\pars{x} \over x^{7/4}}
\,\pars{3 \pm x^{1/2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ \to\ \infty}\!\!\!\!\!\arctan\pars{x}
\,\dd\bracks{\pars{-4x^{-3/4}} \pm \pars{-4x^{-1/4}}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mbox{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,&
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-3/4} \pm x^{-1/4} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-7/8} \pm x^{-5/8} \over x + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{t\ =\ 1/\pars{x + 1} \iff x = 1/t - 1}{=}\,\,\,&
\int_{1}^{0}t\bracks{\pars{{1 \over t} - 1}^{-7/8} \pm
\pars{{1 \over t} - 1}^{-5/8}}\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/8}\,\pars{1 - t}^{-7/8}\,\dd t \pm
\int_{0}^{1}t^{-3/8}\,\pars{1 - t}^{-5/8}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{\Gamma\pars{7/8}\Gamma\pars{1/8} \over \Gamma\pars{1}} \pm
{\Gamma\pars{5/8}\Gamma\pars{3/8} \over \Gamma\pars{1}} =
{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/8}} \pm {\pi \over \sin\pars{3\pi/8}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\bracks{{1 \over \sin\pars{\pi/8}} \pm {1 \over \cos\pars{\pi/8}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\,\braces{%
{\root{\bracks{1 + \cos\pars{\pi/4}}/2} \over \sin\pars{\pi/4}} \pm
{\root{\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{\pi/4}}/2} \over \sin\pars{\pi/4}}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\pi\,{\root{2 + \root{2}} \pm \root{2 - \root{2}} \over \root{2}}
= \bbx{\root{2 \pm \root{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

By setting $x=\arctan t$ we are left with
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(t^2)}{t^{5/2}}(3\pm t)\,dt \stackrel{t\mapsto\sqrt{u}}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{3\pm\sqrt{u}}{u^{7/4}}\arctan(u)\,du \tag{1}$$
and we may apply Feynman's trick to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{3\pm\sqrt{u}}{u^{7/4}}\arctan(\alpha u)\,du$. We have:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(3\pm\sqrt{u})u}{u^{7/4}(1+\alpha^2 u^2)}\,du = \frac{\pi}{2\alpha^{3/4}}\left(3\sqrt{\alpha}\csc\frac{\pi}{8}\pm\sec\frac{\pi}{8}\right) \tag{2}$$
for any $\alpha<0$ by the residue theorem, hence the claim readily follows by integrating $(2)$ over $(0,1)$.